Convert Outlook OST to CSV in PowerShell
I am trying to convert an MS Outlook OST file to a PST file.
I thought I could run a Power Shell script to get it into CSV format, then import that to a new PST file in Outlook.
My script. (Before running it, I run the "Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted" command):
New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application | %{
$_.Session.AddStoreFromFile("k:\admin-aerial.ost")
$_.Session.GetDefaultFolder(6).Items |
Select-Object -Property Subject, ReceivedTime, SenderEmailAddress |
Export-Csv -Path "k:\admin-aerial.csv" -NoTypeInformation

Ran the script in PS and got the error message:

Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpaceClass] does not contain a method named 'AddStoreFromFile'


I think you want the AddStore method

Namespace object does not expose AddStoreFromFile, only AddStore / AddStoreEx. Both of these methods only work with PST files You cannot open a standalone OST file - OST files only exist within their parent profiles. You cannot move an OST file to another machine or even a another profile on the same machine.

If you have your original Outlook account, it can simply export your data from your profile to a new PST. Later you can import it into new Outlook & access your data. If profile is not available or inaccessible so you need to use 3rd party tool.
